# Код не работает в Visual C++ 2010

Tags: windows, c++

но вот теперь еще одна ерунда.
программа сверху заработала, это радостно))
теперь вот я ввожу код из книги, там написано что всё оттуда работало. на C++ visual 2006, но у меня не работает в 2010.
это нормально? 
вот кстати пример :

```
// Программа дважды два
#include <iostream.h>
int main ()
{ cout <<"2 * 2 = " << 2*2 << endl;
return 0;
}
```

выдает кучу ошибок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 ошибки.

Во-первых, у меня 2010 студия и там к стандартным файлам инклуда (куда относится iostream) не нужно писать расширение .h

Во-вторых, вам нужно написать "using namespace std;" или как написано в примере у userx - т.к. для cout, cin, endl нужно указать что они из стандартной библиотеки.

Вроде как то так :).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{ 
    cout <<"2 * 2 = " << 2*2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш код проходит проверку на ошибки, компилируется, появляется окно с командной строкой и через секунду всё исчезает, как и не бывало.

Comment: Додумался, что надо писать, чтобы программа работала. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Можно написать system("PAUSE >> void"); и тогда закрываться не должно. Ещё с cin можно по экспериментировать.